# Having issue with Jquery UI autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, mysqli

My php code looks like that

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['term']))
{
    $term = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

    $result = $db->query("SELECT company as value,id FROM main WHERE company LIKE '$term'") or die(mysqli_error());;
    $results = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) $results[] = array( 'id' => $row[0] , 'label' => $row[1], 'value' => $row[1] );
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

Js code below

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: "index.php",
    minLength: 2,//search after two characters
    select: function(event,ui){
    }
});
```

And HTML markup

```
<input id="auto" name="company"/>
```

What's wrong with the code? It doesn't generate autocomplete option.. No error in php log file. How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming json is ok then you are not doing anything with data you get back

```
select: function(event,ui){
// do something with the data you get back
//you would usually have a function here to do something with data
// but this sample should be enough for you 
var id = ui.id;  // id you got back assign to var
var label = ui.label; // label you got back assign to var
$('#gothisback').val(ui.id); //push it to a div
    }
```

Comment: which div?  i want to just get it back as autocomplete menu